# How to write on Jenkins console output?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm coding a library for my Jenkins pipelines. I would like to print different formats for my messages, like `[INFO], [WARNING]` and so on.

So far I have this:

```
import org.foo.Output

def call(body) {

    def config = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body.delegate = config
    body()

    def out = new Output()

    node("${config.slaveNodeName}") {
        try {
            stage ('CLONE') {
                out.info("SOME VERY USEFUL INFORMATION")
        ...
```

And at my `org.foo.Output` class:

```
package org.foo

import java.util.logging.Logger


class Output {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Output.class.getName());

    def info(msg){
        LOGGER.info("${msg}")
        echo "[INFO] ${msg}" <-- gives me an exception described below
    }
}
```

I can see the `[INFO] SOME VERY USEFUL INFORMATION` on my Jenkins log, however, I would like to redirect this message to Jenkins output console.

How can I do that?

Exception:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.foog.Output.echo() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [[INFO] SOME VERY USEFUL INFORMATION]
Possible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure), info(java.lang.Object), wait(), grep(), any(), find()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:19)
```

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-echo-code-print-message?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Doesn't work, I have updated my question.

Comment: Within the class it will look for a method; you could do e.g. `def out = new Output(echo)` to give the instance access to the step.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sound a good idea! However, still not working `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: echo for class: standardGradleBuildPipeline`

Answer (score 3):

Valter, try this one. It's working in my scripts, I think it would also work in your scripts.

In groovy script, add this:

```
node("${config.slaveNodeName}") {
        try {
            stage ('CLONE') {
                out.info(this,"SOME VERY USEFUL INFORMATION")
```

and change the class groovy script like this:

```
def info(script,msg){
        LOGGER.info("${msg}")
        script.echo "[INFO] ${msg}"
    }
```